# Derivative of a functional with respect to another functional

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative, gateaux-derivative

I am trying to make sense of functional derivatives and have a couple of questions bothering me:

1. Let $F[X]$ be a functional of $X(t)$ and $G[X]$ another functional of $X(t)$.

   By chain rule in the continum I intuitively guess that the derivative of the functional F[X] with respect to the functional G[X] is:$$\frac{\delta F}{\delta G} = \int dt \frac{\delta F[X]}{\delta X(t)} \frac{\delta X(t)}{\delta G[X]} = \int dt \frac{\delta F[X]}{\delta X(t)} \left(\frac{\delta G[X]}{\delta X(t)} \right)^{-1} $$
   Does this make any sense at all? Is there such thing as a derivative of a functional with respect to another functional given they are both dependent on the same underlying function X(t)?
2. How would one calculate the functional derivatives $\frac{\delta F[X]}{\delta X(t)}$ and $\frac{\delta G[X]}{\delta X(t)}$? I came across Gateaux derivative and It seems to be similar to a directional derivative. Does it matter what direction is being chosen to evaluate the final functional derivative?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Please rewrite.

Comment: Thanks Will, just edited please let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: OK. It still makes no sense. However, two points to bring. (1) Frechet derivative _is_ simply the usual derivative on learns from calculus 2 (at least in places like the one I studied where math rigour is imposed over being able to perform calculations) and (2) Gateaux derivatives _are_ directional derivatives and, as always, they depend on the chosen direction.

If you want to know the derivatives of a composition $g \circ f,$ then simply apply the chain rule $g'(f(a)) \circ f'(a).$ If you want to know how to calculate $f'$ or $g',$ you need to know the exact form first an apply rules then.

Comment: @ZeroCool you might want to ask on MathOverflow. This site is for more elementary questions (usually pre-functional-derivative stage).