# Functional Derivative with Difficult Chain Rule

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, chain-rule, functional-calculus

I am trying to evaluate the functional derivatives $\dfrac{\delta F[\phi(\textbf{r})]}{\delta n_{1}}$ and $\dfrac{\delta F[\phi(\textbf{r})]}{\delta n_{2}}$ where

\begin{gather}
F[\phi_1(\textbf{r}), \phi_2(\textbf{r})] = \int d \textbf{r} \bigl [ f (\phi_{1}(\textbf{r}), \phi_{2}(\textbf{r}), \nabla\phi_{1}(\textbf{r}), \nabla\phi_{2}(\textbf{r}) ) \bigr ] \\
n_{1}[\phi_1(\textbf{r})] = \int d\textbf{r} \, g_{1} (\phi_{1}(\textbf{r})) \\
n_{2}[\phi_2(\textbf{r})] = \int d\textbf{r} \, g_{2} (\phi_{2}(\textbf{r}))
\end{gather}

I have explicit expressions for $f$, $g_1$ and $g_2$. I believe the appropriate chain rule for functional derivatives is given by

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta F[\phi_1, \phi_2]}{\delta n_{1}} = \int d\textbf{r} \left ( \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi_1} \frac{\delta \phi_{1}}{\delta n_1} +  \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi_2} \frac{\delta \phi_{2}}{\delta n_1}\right) \textrm{.}
\end{equation}

But the chain rule is only useful if I know  $\phi_1[n_1]$, when in fact I have the inverse. How can I evaluate these derivatives?

Related: [Derivative of a functional with respect to another functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016507/derivative-of-a-functional-with-respect-to-another-functional)

Comment: When you write $g_k(\phi_k)$ do you mean $g_k \circ \phi_k$? Are the integration limits dependent on $r$? Are the various functions sufficiently smooth?

Comment: Yes, $g_k \circ \phi_k$. The limits of integration do not depend on r. One can assume natural/periodic boundary conditions. The functions are smooth.